# Unable to click after Alt + Tab switch

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, freeze

Ever since 20.04 I have an issue with Alt + Tab.
Sometimes, randomly, I cannot click on anything after I switch windows with that shortcut until I use Alt + Tab 2 - 3 times after it's occurence.

Anyone else has this issue? I am sure it's a bug but cannot find which that would be and how to work around it as is breaks my workflow.

Using Ubuntu 20.04.2 AMD64, with Gnome shell 3.36.8.
uname -a: `Linux vadrian-ubuntu 5.8.0-44-generic #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

It is specific to Gnome, as I've tried Unity and didn't had this issue.

Comment: how about power (windows) key tab?

Comment: I don't use Windows + tab.

Comment: my suggestion was that you do so to see if that makes any difference . all keyboards have a "windows" key. we can put a penguin sticker on it for Linux if we choose to though. :-). you could also try some of the alternative windows switchers  https://extensions.gnome.org/# type "switcher windows". I'd recommend a system backup before doing anything.

Comment: I understand your recommendation. The thing is, after years of using Alt + Tab is hard to change how I switch windows and all for the sake of a bug.
I thank you for your input though.

Comment: most of those extensions would use the alt tab keys as they are alternatives. did you try power/windows key and tab? and if in the unlikely event that works, you could do a ubuntu shortcut key to overide alt-tab (probably) to use power/windows tab with 'xinput key alt + tab'

Answer (score 0):

If you can't click on anything after using the "Alt+Tab" shortcut, the system is freezing (possibly due to a memory shortage).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't see how that is the case here.
For example, after reading your answer I decided to check the monitor application when the issue occurs. It occured earlier, and I was at 11.1/15.5 GB RAM & 121 MB/7,8 GB of swap.